# Asserting On Asynchronous Behavior

Tags: apex, unit-test, future, asynchronous-testing

I have a future method with some logic and I have written Test class for that.

1. Calling future method inside test.startTest() and test.StopTest() in test class and asserting the values, in this case i'm getting 100% Coverage for the class which has future method.
2. In this case i'm not including test.starttest() and test.stopTest(). here also i can assert the results and i'm getting 100% coverage for the class - **Same Results In both cases**

> As per my understanding from the documentation, we should include all asynchronous calls between those two methods so that we can assert the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure the asynchronous processing has complete in order to properly verify its behavior. If your tests are both passing, you likely are *not* correctly asserting that the `@future` method was executed. In other words, if you have not yet called `stopTest`, the underlying behavior you are testing has not yet been executed.

Let's consider a trivial example:

```
@future
public static void createChildContact(Id accountId, String lastName)
{
    insert new Contact(AccountId=accountId, LastName=lastName);
}
```

Now, this test will fail:

```
static testMethod void testCreateChildContact()
{
    final String LAST_NAME = 'Smith';
    Account parent = new Account(Name='ACME');
    insert parent;

    // omit Test.startTest();
        MyClass.createChildContact(parent.Id, LAST_NAME);
    // omit Test.stopTest();

    List<Contact> children = [SELECT AccountId, LastName FROM Contact];
    system.assertEquals(1, children.size(), 'A Contact should be created');
    system.assertEquals(parent.Id, children[0].AccountId, '<some_message>');
    system.assertEquals(LAST_NAME, children[0].LastName, '<some_message>');
}
```

While this test will succeed:

```
static testMethod void testCreateChildContact()
{
    final String LAST_NAME = 'Smith';
    Account parent = new Account(Name='ACME');
    insert parent;

    Test.startTest();
        MyClass.createChildContact(parent.Id, LAST_NAME);
    Test.stopTest();

    List<Contact> children = [SELECT AccountId, LastName FROM Contact];
    system.assertEquals(1, children.size(), 'A Contact should be created');
    system.assertEquals(parent.Id, children[0].AccountId, '<some_message>');
    system.assertEquals(LAST_NAME, children[0].LastName, '<some_message>');
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested properly before seeing this. Now i got what i wanted, Thanks @Adrian